# ASCII text to Hexadecimal in Excel

Tags: excel, character-encoding, hex

I want to this but i don't know what to do, the only functions it seems to be useful is "DEC.TO.HEX".

This is the problem, i have in one cell this text:

```
1234
```

And in the next cell i want the hexadecimal value of each character, the expected result would be:

```
31323334
```

Each character must be represented by two hexadecimal characters. I don't have an idea how to solve this in excel avoiding make a coded program.

Regards!

Edit: Hexadecimal conversion

```
Text value      Ascii Value (Dec)    Hexadecimal Value
    1              49                    31
    2              50                    32
    3              51                    33
    4              52                    34
```

Comment: Hi @pnuts, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @pnuts , My original question? It is simple. I have in one cell the value "1234" and i need to make a formula in another one to convert that value (ascii text) to its hexadecimal equivalent. "31323334" in this case.

Comment: @pnuts, It is ascii value for "1234". See my edit, i think you will understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,1,1)))&DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,2,1)))&DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,3,1)))&DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,4,1)))
```

In your version you might need the `.`s in the function (and perhaps `;`s rather than `,`s).

Comment: Thanks @pnuts, I though to do that but I really don't know the length of the string. In this case "1234" has four characters, but if i write another value with different length your formula won't work.

Comment: This is perfect for fixed ranged values. I padded simply by manually adding in my 000 pad as 303030etc.

Answer (score 0):

[DEC2HEX](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/dec2hex-function-6344ee8b-b6b5-4c6a-a672-f64666704619) may be of assistance. Use, as follows:

```
=DEC2HEX(A3)
```

Comment: This only applies to the first character.

Answer (score 0):

First split `1234` to `1 2 3 4` by using `MID()`, then use `Code()` for each character, and then again concentate. Below is the formula, `Y21` is the cell in which `1234` is written

`=CONCATENATE(CODE(MID(Y21,1,1)),CODE(MID(Y21,2,1)),CODE(MID(Y21,3,1)),CODE(MID(Y21,4,1)))`

`1234   >>  49505152`

Comment: This only does half the job. OP wanted Ascii Hex values, not Ascii Decimal values. Ascii Char 1 = Decimal 49 = Hex 31.